# from vosk import Model, KaldiRecognizer ImportError: No module named vosk

Tags: raspberry-pi, putty, orange-pi, vosk

I am working with vosk software using orange pi zero 256mb and python.  I try so many idea and always ı see this error. I installed old version of Vosk and download old-new  (.whl) file  make a virtual environment (env) but doesnt work anyone. Please help

**Note:**

- This code works on Pc-python.
- Pip and python all the last version.
- I was just able to upload this "Vosk-0.3.44-py3-none-linux_armv7l.whl" .  The other versions not supported.

```py
    from vosk import Model, KaldiRecognizer
    import os
    if not os.path.exists("tr"):
        exit (1)
    import pyaudio
    p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
    stream = p.open(format=pyaudio.paInt16, channels=1, rate=16000, input=True, frames_per_buffer=8000)
    stream.start_stream()
    model = Model("tr")
    rec = KaldiRecognizer(model, 16000)
    while True:
       data = stream.read(2000, exception_on_overflow = False)
       if len(data) == 0:
           break
       if rec.AcceptWaveform(data):
           print(rec.Result())
    print(rec.FinalResult())
```